# Using sass map key as a variable

Tags: sass

I am developing a utility/helper-class for a hamburger menu, and this needs some math to get the spacing between bars right. I am trying to use nested lists to loop through both bar `size - 2(px)` and `3(px)`, as well as spacing for 3 different sizes. I am trying to extract the menu line size from the map key (2, 3), but I having some trouble making this work. Right now, the `$px-variable` outputs the entire list, is there a way to make it output the key as an integer (2 and 3)?

```scss
$menus: (
  2: ( s: 14, m: 19, l: 22),
  3: ( s: 22, m: 25, l: 29)
);
@each $menu in $menus {
  @each $key, $sz in $menu {
    .menu-#{$px}px-#{$key} {
      $menu-height: $sz * 1px;
      $menu-line: $px * 1px;
      $menu-space: ($menu-height - ($menu-line*3))/2;

      height: $menu-height;
      width: $menu-height*1.33;

      span {
        &, &:before, &:after { height: $menu-line; }
        & { margin-top: $menu-space + $menu-line; }
        &:before { margin-top: -$menu-space; }
        &:after { margin-top: $menu-space; }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the loops to output six menu-classes, like this:

```
.menu-2px-s {
      $menu-height: 14px;
      $menu-line: 2px;
      ...
}
.menu-2px-m {
      $menu-height: 19px;
      $menu-line: 2px;
      ...
}
.menu-2px-l {
      $menu-height: 22px;
      $menu-line: 2px;
      ...
}
.menu-3px-s {
      $menu-height: 22px;
      $menu-line: 2px;
      ...
}
.menu-3px-m {
      $menu-height: 25px;
      $menu-line: 2px;
      ...
}
.menu-3px-l {
      $menu-height: 29px;
      $menu-line: 2px;
      ...
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about  what you want. Could you post an example of what you want to achieve? Anyways, I get 14 with this: `.class{property: map-get(map-get($menus, 2),s)} `.

Comment: Updated my post with the desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the key in the first iteration. Also you were using a undefined variable `$px`.

```
$menus: (
  2: ( s: 14, m: 19, l: 22),
  3: ( s: 22, m: 25, l: 29)
);
@each $num, $menu in $menus {
  @each $key, $sz in $menu {
    .menu-#{$num}px-#{$key} {
      $menu-height: $sz * 1px;
      $menu-line: $num * 1px;
      $menu-space: ($menu-height - ($menu-line*3))/2;

      height: $menu-height;
      width: $menu-height*1.33;

      span {
        &, &:before, &:after { height: $menu-line; }
        & { margin-top: $menu-space + $menu-line; }
        &:before { margin-top: -$menu-space; }
        &:after { margin-top: $menu-space; }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was getting pretty close, was just confused by how I could make a new iteration when I had both $num/key and $menu in the first iteration